# What does this query do in SQL Server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am reading somebody's code and I don't quite get this.

```
DECLARE  @return int 
EXEC @return = dbo.Update
```

If you are setting return to be an integer, what does the next line mean?  How can you set @return to a stored procedure?  Does the stored procedure get called?

Comment: Yes, it's being called, and the `RETURN` result of the proc is being set to `@return`.  For example:  if at the end of the proc there is a `RETURN 0` statement, after executing, `@return` will have a value of `0`.

Comment: Have you tried running it?

Comment: Technically this is not a query but a "batch".

Answer (score 4):

Yes the stored procedure is called and the return value is stored in `@return`

As [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure) says :

> A procedure can return an integer value called a return code to indicate the execution status of a procedure. You specify the return code for a procedure using the RETURN statement. As with OUTPUT parameters, you must save the return code in a variable when the procedure is executed in order to use the return code value in the calling program. For example, the assignment variable @result of data type int is used to store the return code from the procedure my_proc, such as:
>
> ```
> DECLARE @result int;  
> EXECUTE @result = my_proc;
> ```
>
> Return codes are commonly used in control-of-flow blocks within procedures to set the return code value for each possible error situation. You can use the @@ERROR function after a Transact-SQL statement to detect whether an error occurred during the execution of the statement.

Answer (score 0):

That returns the `return value` from a stored procedure. If a value is not explicitly returned (e.g. `return 2;`) in the procedure then it will return `0` for a successful execution, or a negative value if an error was encountered.

Reference:

- [`return` (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/return-transact-sql)

---

Here are some quick examples:

```
create proc dbo.AllGood as
begin;
  select 1 as One into #temp;
end;
go
create proc dbo.ReturnOneForOdd (@i int) as
begin;
  if (@i % 2) = 1 return 1;
end;
go
create proc dbo.DivByZero as
begin;
  begin try
    select 1/0;
  end try
  begin catch
  end catch;
end;
go

declare @r int;

exec @r = dbo.AllGood;
select @r as AllGood; /* returns 0 */

exec @r = dbo.ReturnOneForOdd 1 ;
select @r as ReturnOneForOdd; /* returns 1 */

exec @r = dbo.ReturnOneForOdd 2;
select @r as ReturnOneForOdd; /* returns 0 */

exec @r = dbo.DivByZero;
select @r as DivByZero; /* returns -6 */
```

rextester demo: http://rextester.com/WPNHX39195

Comment: That makes sense.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Check [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/stored-procedures/return-data-from-a-stored-procedure) for more details regarding storing stored procedure output to a variable. And Stored procedure with `OUTPUT` variable as parameter.